# Azure Active Directory for Botframework

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I want to retain my pass conversation by refreshing the token before it expires. But the problem was if I logout and close the site. So basically it won't run the refresh/token endpoint. Is there a way that it will refresh itself even if I'm not using the Bot? I read the AAD but I have no idea how to implement it. I am using the Reactjs Botframework on the client side and the .Net bot framework.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow, but I assume you meant 'past conversation'. Meaning you want to save the conversation(s) that users have had with the bot. This is going to depend on what you've setup for state storage. And how you've implemented that (and what exactly you've stored).

Creating a new secret won't affect any of the above. The only caveat is if you are using Memory State for storage (bad idea anyhow), then that would be lost if your App Service/Web App ever gets restarted.

---

Update:

You might be able to setup a separate service that your page that hosts web chat could call. It could send the token which saves it and periodically refreshes. When the page starts up, it could make a call to this service to obtain the new token. I'm not sure the value gained for all the work to set that up is worth it. It's also just a theory.

These might be helpful as well:

- [How to reconnect WebChat to old conversation with an expired token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63782062/how-to-reconnect-webchat-to-old-conversation-with-an-expired-token/63801952)
- [Botframework Create Directline get token from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63823755/botframework-create-directline-get-token-from-server/63837881)
- [How to subscribe to the refresh token event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59247586/how-to-subscribe-to-the-refresh-token-event/59274160)

Comment: Yea2, the 'past conversation'. Note, I'm not using any state storage on the .Net bot framework. I can retain the conversation if the token is not expired yet this is using the React botframework-webchat.

Comment: Gotcha. My apologies, i think I totally misunderstood your original ask. I also think there is some confusion around the tokens. You are wanting to update the token generated for web chat, and I was assuming you were wanting to update the bot AAD app registration's secret. I'll modify my answer above for clarity.